# Counting Digits in Floats (Python)

Tags: python

How can you get the total number of digits in floating numbers? I used math.log10() but that only gives me the number of digits that come before the decimal. I want to find the number of digits in the entire float.

Comment: `len(str(12.123123).replace('.', ''))` convert to a string and get the length

Comment: This depends on exactly what you mean. Floats don't contain "digits", at least not decimal digits. Their fundamental representation is binary. Usually when you print a float, it isn't giving you the exact number, rather, the shortest decimal representation to accurately reproduce it.

Comment: How many digits does `9.3 - 0.1` contain? [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](//docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Also how many digits would `1.0 / 3.0` be? If you are referring to the string representation of the float, that would essentially depend on how many significant figures you intend to display.

Comment: Chris's code was exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: As pointed you will not get exact decimal nos. Lets say `a = 12324.1335464646` . if you do `a - int(a)`, then you will get `0.13354646459993091`